# django post checkbox data

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a checkbox form in my template and in my view im trying to check if the box has been checked or not
I have the following code in my view:

```
if request.POST['check'] == True:
```

but then it throws an error if it is unchecked. How do i check if there is a value 'check' in my post data?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use forms?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) are your friend:

```
 if request.POST.get('check', False):
     ...do stuff...
```

You could also do this ([more Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)):

```
 if "check" in request.POST:
     ... do stuff...
```

Comment: and you don't need `keys()` in the second one - `if "check" in request.POST` is the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: It is not just explicit, it is also slower. 'if key in dict' is faster than 'if key in dict.keys()', the first one uses built in hashes O(1) whereas second one is a list lookup O(N).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
request.POST.get('field_name', '') == 'on'
```

---

Note: another proposed solution

```
request.POST.get('check', False) # do not use it
```

led to this error for me:

```
['“on” value must be either True or False.']
```

when the checkbox is selected.