# Detect if checkbox is ticked?

Tags: python, django

In django I do the following to get the value of an text box for example:

On my HTML page:

```
<input type="text" name="inputBox" id="inputBox" />
```

ON the views.py page:

```
valueOfTextBox= request.POST.get('inputBox', False)
```

How do I get whether a ceck box is 'checked' or not??

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
```

Comment: did one of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the inputBox is included in request.POST it has been checked. Therefore you could do the following.

```
 if request.POST.get('selectAll', False):
     ...do stuff...
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223247/237690) answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same, just write:

```
request.POST.get('selectAll', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have value="" attribute on you checkbox so in case it is checked, your POST variable will have value 'on', if not checked, the variable will not be in your POST dict. So you can check it like described in previous answers.

PS: You don't need to write False as the second parameter to get() method, it will automatically return None what is in boolean the same as False.